# How to make <a> in table cell height 100%?

Tags: css

I have a table with clickable rows using this js:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".clickableRow").click(function () {
        window.document.location = $(this).attr("href");
    });
```

but, I have ajax search for data in table and when is table displayed by ajax, js doesn't work any more. So I wrap every content of every  with  in that ajax table. So it is looks like: http://jsfiddle.net/fo1tvdyf/4/

Width works fine, but height isn't 100% :( Any one have some idea? Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give your `a` `display:inline-block` so it can correctly assume any given dimensions

Assuming your `a` has the class `clickableRow`:

```
.clickableRow{
   display:inline-block;
}
```

Though note that percentage values are calculated relative to the parent container- as such, you may also need to give the encapsulating element a height value.